What Vim Fn provides me the search direction?
getcharsearch provides the search direction for the inline search (t, f, T, F) but I couldn't find a function for search directions from / or ?.
Any suggestion?
Similarly to getcharsearch I'm looking for a function that provides me the same / similar info for / or ?
ps: I'm working on a Lualine component to provide some indicators in the statusline according to the user search.

Are you looking for search()?

Hmm it seems in search() we can provide a flag to indicate if I want the search to be done forward or backward. I'm actually looking to something similar to getcharsearch which provides me a table with the search direction user tried to run. I couldn't find it the docs so wondering if such func or variable exists.

See :help v:searchforward.

/ always searches forward and ? backward. You probably mean n and N instead. They are governed by v:searchforward variable (which in turn is toggled by / and ?).
